# Work with manually created tables in jpa

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I've manually created tables via SQL.

```
    CREATE TABLE author(
author_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20),
author_phone_fk INT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  `author_phone_fk`
FOREIGN KEY(author_phone_fk) REFERENCES phone(phone_id));

CREATE TABLE phone(
phone_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
number VARCHAR(20));
```

and I've classes

```
@Entity
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "phone_id")
    private int id;

    private String number;

  }

@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "author_id")
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_phone_fk")
    private Phone phone;
}
```

While saving Author object I've exception

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`final_project`.`author`, CONSTRAINT `author_phone_fk` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`author_phone_fk`) REFERENCES `phone` (`phone_id`))

I've not idea how to fix the error. Tnx

Test data:

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

        transaction.begin();

        Phone myPhone = new Phone("89198130228");

        Author myAuthor = new Author("Alex", myPhone);

        em.persist(myAuthor);

        transaction.commit();

        em.close();
```

Stacktrace:

> Hibernate: insert into Phone (number, phone_id) values (?, ?)
>   Hibernate: insert into Author (name, author_phone_fk, author_id)
>   values (?, ?, ?) Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
>   transaction   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:77)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
>     at domain.TestAdvert.main(TestAdvert.java:44) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`final_project`.`author`, CONSTRAINT `author_phone_fk` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`author_phone_fk`) REFERENCES `phone` (`phone_id`))

Comment: You could try @JoinColumn(name="author_phone_fk", insertable=true, updatable=true)

Comment: @Anil Agrawal, thank you, but these comments are true by default

Comment: An exception is thrown when you try to add some data, but you don't post WHAT data you are adding, what lifecycle state the objects are in, or what data is already present.

Comment: @Billy Frost, I've updated question, tnank you

Comment: ok, and now post the SQL statements that your JPA provider tries to execute (in its log).

Comment: @Billy Frost, I've added stacktrace to question

Comment: Don't use 0 as the ID value of your Phone. Make it an Integer rather than an int, and assign it a non-null, non-zero value.

Comment: @JB Nizet, Do I need assigned id manually for phone? And how I can avoid non-zero value, if statement? Thank you

Comment: Well, your ID isn't autogenerated, so you need to provide a value. For example by taking it as argument along with the name in the constructor, or using a setter method.

Comment: But I use AUTO_INCREMENT, starting with 1 via sql for Phone table, is it work?

Comment: Then you need to annotate your Phone.id field accordingly, so that JPA knows that it shouldn't pass the ID, and should instead ask the database which value it has generated for the ID. Read the documentation.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thank you, I create manually tables and add @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) and all works fine